# Lookup from a 3-column table and interpolate one of the columns?

Tags: c#, algorithm, lookup-tables, linear-interpolation

I have a table with 3 columns: Temperature, Pressure, and Gain.

```
interface IEntry
{
    public float Temperature {get;}
    public int Pressure {get;}
    public float Gain {get;}
}
```

Given a certain "input" pair (Temperature_input, Pressure_input), I would like to match this pair with the ones in the table and lookup the corresponding gains, interpolating in certain cases.

Example:

```
T   P   G
3   1   0
3   2   1
3   3   2
3   5   4
6   1   0
6   2   2
6   3   3
8   1   0
8   2   3
9   1   0
```

Input pair `(T = 4, P = 2)`:

Step 1: As the exact temperature T = 4 is not in the table, the immediate lower and upper temperatures 3 and 6 are examined (8 table entries)

Step 2: The pairs for T = 3, T = 6 are sorted by Pressure (which is an int)

```
3   1   0
6   1   0
3   2   1
6   2   2
3   3   2
6   3   3
3   5   4
3   5   4
```

Step 3: Linear interpolation between temperatures of the same pressure:

```
3   2   1
6   2   2
```

Result is the interpolated Gain = `1 + (2-1)/(6-3) = 1.33`

What is an efficient way of implementing the lookup part of the table, that will be accessed millions of times?

Comment: *"As T = 4 is not in the table, temperatures 3 and 6 are examined"* - why 3 and 6? Why not only 3? Why not 8 as well? *"1 + (2-1)/(6-3)*" - what are these numbers? What is 1? Why 2-1 ?

Comment: As the exact temperature T = 4 is not in the table, the immediate lower and upper temperatures 3 and 6 are examined.

Comment: An "efficient" way is to stop interpolating lookup tables and start using something like polynomial regression (though this will lose precision in order to gain efficiency). This also depends on the size of your current lookup table.

Comment: If it is possible, have you considered sorting the table (by row) and then performing binary searches? Also, please provide detailed information as it is unclear what `1 + (2-1)/(6-3) = 1.33` is supposed to represent.

Comment: I would use an optimized k-nearest neighbors library to find the 3 closest points, treating the temperature and pressure as the x and y locations in a 2-dimensional grid. If any of these 3 points are an exact match, fine. If not I can fit a linear function k + ax + by to 3 points and then evaluate this at the input temperature and pressure to get my estimate.